# How .fnDestroy(),columnFilter(); both will work..Is there any way to do it. Currently only .fnDestroy is working

Tags: javascript, jquery

How .fnDestroy(),columnFilter(); both will work..Is there any way to do it. Currently only .fnDestroy is working.

The code describing the issue with DataTable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var exampleResponsiveHelper = undefined;

    var nomineeTableResponsiveHelper = undefined;
    var coverageTableResponsiveHelper = undefined;
    var agentInfoTableResponsiveHelper = undefined;
    var payoutTableResponsiveHelper = undefined;
    var payoutTable1ResponsiveHelper = undefined;
    var payoutTable2ResponsiveHelper = undefined;
    var payoutTable3ResponsiveHelper = undefined;
    var payoutTable4ResponsiveHelper = undefined;
    var payoutTable5ResponsiveHelper = undefined;

    var breakpointDefinition = {
        tablet: 1024,
        phone : 480
    };

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var tableElement = $('#example');

    tableElement.dataTable({
        autoWidth        : false,

        preDrawCallback: function () {
            // Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
            if (!exampleResponsiveHelper) {
                exampleResponsiveHelper = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper(tableElement, breakpointDefinition);
            }
        },
        rowCallback    : function (nRow) {
            exampleResponsiveHelper.createExpandIcon(nRow);
        },
        drawCallback   : function (oSettings) {
            exampleResponsiveHelper.respond();
        }
    }).fnDestroy(),columnFilter();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To chain the commands use `.fnDestroy().columnFilter();`

You used comma in your code.

Comment: glad to help. Please accept the answer if it helped you.